# Solution for "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."

Tags: entity-framework, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I encountered this error, it did not provide any detail as to what the root cause was but I figured out what the problem is.  I wanted to share it so that others that encounter it might have success in solving the problem.

I had the following class:

```
    public class BankUser : IdentityUser, IUserProfile
{
    #region IUserProfile Members
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Time Zone")]
    public int TimeZone { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> TimeZoneOptions
    {
        get
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            d.Add("(GMT -10:00) Hawaii", "-10");
            d.Add("(GMT -9:00) Alaska", "-9");
            d.Add("(GMT -8:00) Pacific Time", "-8");
            d.Add("(GMT -7:00) Mountain Time", "-7");
            d.Add("(GMT -6:00) Central Time", "-6");
            d.Add("(GMT -5:00) Eastern Time", "-5");
            d.Add("Unknown", "0");
            return d;
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Invalid phone number.")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Phone number must be 10 characters long.")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

As you can see, I extended IdentityUser with additional properties. My view only had UserName and Password as form fields when trying to create a new user `UserManager.CreateAsync()`. When trying to submit the form with just the UserName and Password the system would try to validate that Email was passed since it had the Required attribute.

```
        //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new BankUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, and then accept your own answer, since it really isn't looking for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
I must either add the Email as a field in my form or remove the Required attribute.  Once I did either of them the code worked as expected.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Entity Framework:

**Error Message (from the Update-Database command in the PMC):**
*Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.*

**Solution:**
*One cause of this problem is validation errors when the Seed method runs. See Seeding and Debugging Entity Framework (EF) DBs for tips on debugging the Seed method.*

For more information please visit: [Advanced Entity Framework 6 Scenarios for an MVC 5 Web Application (12 of 12)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're passing null value when create ApplicationUser instance.
In my case, i set Postcode isn't required in ViewModel, but in IdentityModel PostCode's still required.
So, you should remove Required annotation of PostCode in IdentityModel. And add Migration to Update Database.