# How can I get all Validation Errors?

Tags: entity-framework, validationerror

I want to get all validation errors.

Can I get errors in DbEntityValidationException ?

```
DbEntityValidationException ex = exception as DbEntityValidationException
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22500988/150342

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string GetAllExceptionTree(Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception is DbEntityValidationException)
        {
            StringBuilder validationErrors = new StringBuilder();
            DbEntityValidationException ex = exception as DbEntityValidationException;
            foreach (var error in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                foreach (var err in error.ValidationErrors)
                    validationErrors.Append(String.Format("{0}<br/>", err.ErrorMessage));

            return validationErrors.ToString();
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        do
        {
            if (sb.Length != 0)
                sb.Append("...");
            sb.Append(exception.Message);
            exception = exception.InnerException;
        } while (exception != null);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```