# How do you retrieve the Exception number from DbUpdateException in Asp.net 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd rather not do string comparison and it looks like my exeption number is in the InnerExeption number field but I get build errors if I try to access it directly.

```
try {
    db.SaveChanges();
} catch (Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbUpdateException ex) {
    // ex.InternalException.Number won't compile but appears to be there

    // ex.InternalException.Message does compile but I think it seems less clean than a const comparison
}
```

Once I do get the number is there a const I can compare it with? I'm trying to check for duplicate key error.

Thanks

Comment: I don't [see](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Core/DbUpdateException.cs) a DbUpdateException.Number

Comment: Take a look at the answers from 'Colin' and 'a-h' on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490842/finding-the-reason-for-dbupdateexception -- I think that their approaches to catching the Exceptions and giving feedback from them, should give the details you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

```
db.User.Add(user);
try {
    db.SaveChanges();
} catch (Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbUpdateException ex) {
    if (((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)ex.InnerException).Number == 2627) {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(409);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a 2 day waiting period then forgot

Comment: In my case, I have to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead of System.Data.SqlClient