# Does Execute extension throw DbUpdateException?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dapper

I'm adding a new method in my generic repository to delete a record directly from the db, instead of going through the `DbConext` and then calling its `SaveChanges`.

So I did:

```
    public virtual void Delete(int id)
    {
        var connection = dataContext.GetDatabase().Connection;
        var query = string.Format("DELETE FROM {0} WHERE id = {1}", tableName, id);

        connection.Execute(query);
    }
```

My current code that deletes entities using the `DbContext` handles `DbUpdateException`, and this exception bubbles up to the client.

Does Dapper's `Execute` extension also throws this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. no it doesn't; if you want that, you should be doing things like `select @@rowcount` after the `delete` in the tsql, using `ExecuteScalar<int>`, and checking that the number returned is `1`. If you want timestamp checking, you would include that in the `where` clause and as a parameter
2. **never, never, never** concatenate inputs into the data part of SQL; it creates a SQL injection risk, and destroys all query / operation caches - the first reason is all you should ever need, though. There is a bit of a caveat here around things like table names, but you should be white-listing there. Note that dapper supports full parameterization (easy parameter handling is one of the main reasons to use it!)

For example, I would be doing something like:

```
public YourType(string tableName) { // constructor
    WhiteList.AssertValid(tableName); // throws if not allowed
    deleteCommand = $"DELETE FROM [{tableName}] WHERE id = @id; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;";
}
private readonly string deleteCommand;
public virtual void Delete(int id)
{
    var connection = dataContext.GetDatabase().Connection;
    int count = connection.ExecuteScalar<int>(deleteCommand, new { id });
    if(count != 0) throw new DbUpdateException();
}
```

Alternatively, use an add-on tool like dapper-contrib that does all this stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer to actual question but imho, you should go for

[Finding the reason for DbUpdateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490842/finding-the-reason-for-dbupdateexception)

That way, you can override Execute method, get to the root cause and solve it for good.

Comment: In my scenario it might happen that the db admin "unwittingly" changes something in the db (eg, foreign key, add/change columns, etc). Therefore I need to catch the exception so we can locate the problem and solve it.