# Error in Entity Framework while inserting

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting this error in Entity Framework while inserting. An error occurred while updating the entries.

Here is my code:

```
 public static void NewCustomer(string name,string address,string cnicno, string cellno,int productpurchasedid,string comments  )
 {
   using (CRMEntities context = new CRMEntities())
   { 
     Customer cs = new Customer() { name=name , address=address , cnicno = cnicno, cellno =cellno, productpurchasedid = productpurchasedid, comments=comments };
     context.Customers.Add(cs);
     context.SaveChanges();       //Error point
   }
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [While saving some Client note, am getting this error " See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970085/while-saving-some-client-note-am-getting-this-error-see-entityvalidationerro)

Comment: same question as this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970085/while-saving-some-client-note-am-getting-this-error-see-entityvalidationerro

Comment: dear i tried that chunk of code but control is not going in catch block it trhows same exception

Comment: hows that possible that it is not going in catch, how are you putting try catch?

Comment: public static void NewEmployeeRole(string name, string desc)
        {
            try
            {
                using (CRMEntities context = new CRMEntities())
                {
                    EmployeeRole er = new EmployeeRole() { name = name, description = desc };
                    context.EmployeeRoles.Add(er);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
               
                        Console.WriteLine(message);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

Comment: Dear Ehsan.i have not uploaded the catch block code bcz it wasn't toolarge.....Do you know where i am making an error?

Comment: you have to put try catch inside using

Comment: i have putted it inside using block but same exception happening.

Comment: In the exception dialog, click "View Detail" link and let us know what is the value for Inner Exception.

Comment: {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}

Comment: HI Dinesh,did you got any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the ID column in database table has Identity set to true. If not, set it true.

Comment: it is identity and true

Comment: Try replacing...
context.Customers.Add(cs);
with this...
context.Entry(cs).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

Comment: it is throughing error on .EntryState.....Error:does not exist in the namespace system.data.entity

Comment: <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade to EF6?

Comment: may b.nut i don't know how to upgrade and what will be the damages ?

Comment: If it is a legacy application then it may not be a good idea at this stage but if is brand new I'd recommend to upgrade. You can use this reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx

Comment: dear can you tell me that which datasource is used for the gridview using entity framework ?and how to bind it