# Validation failed for one or more entities.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I try to Update IsApproved=true to approve the property, I am getting the following error.
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. The validation errors are: Please upload the image.; Please select some property features.
Please help me out. Thanx in advance.
My Model is as follows:

[Table("AddProperty")]
    public class AddProperty
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

```
    public List<TransactionType> TransactionType_List { get; set; }//Used to populate dropdown list values

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the category.")]
    [Display(Name = "Category:")]
    public int TransactionTypeId { get; set; }//Used to post back selected value

    public virtual TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }

    public List<PropertyType> PropertyType_List { get; set; }//Used to populate dropdown list values

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the property.")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please select the property.")]
    [Display(Name = "Property:")]
    public int PropertyTypeId { get; set; }//Used to post back selected value

    public virtual PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }

    public List<PropertyList> PropertyList_List { get; set; }//Used to populate dropdown list values

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the property type.")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please select the property type.")]
    [Display(Name = "Property Type:")]
    public int PropertyListId { get; set; }//Used to post back selected value

    public virtual PropertyList PropertyList { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Property Name is required.")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Building Name length should be between 3 and 50.")]
    [Display(Name = "Property Name:")]
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public List<FlatDescription> FlatDescription_List { get; set; }//Used to populate dropdown list values

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Description:")]
    public int FlatDescriptionId { get; set; }

    public virtual FlatDescription FlatDescription { get; set; }

    public List<Bathroom> Bathrooms_List { get; set; }//Used to populate dropdown list values

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No of Bathrooms is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "No of Bathrooms:")]
    public int BathroomId { get; set; }//Used to post back selected value

    public virtual Bathroom Bathroom { get; set; }

    public List<City> City_List { get; set; }//Used to populate dropdown list values

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the city.")]
    [Display(Name = "City:")]
    public int CityId { get; set; }//Used to post back selected value

    public virtual City City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location is required.")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Location length should be between 3 and 30.")]
    [Display(Name = "Location:")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Property Price is required.")]
    [Range(typeof(decimal),"1","10000000",ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid property price.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Only 2 decimal point values are allowed.")]
    [Display(Name = "Enter Property Price:")]
    public decimal PropertyPrice { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please upload the image.")]
    [Display(Name = "Upload Image:")]
    [NotMapped]
    [ValidatePhoto]
    public HttpPostedFileBase PropertyPhoto { get; set; }

    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    public List<Facilities> Facilities_List { get; set; }//Used to populate dropdown list values

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select some property features.")]
    [Display(Name = "Select Property Features:")]
    [NotMapped]
    public int[] SelectedIds { get; set; }//Used to post back selected value   

    public string PropertyFeatures { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int CreateUser { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public int? UpdateUser { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }             
}
```

Comment: The error summary seems to suggest that two of your properties are not set. One of them is SelectedIds (error message: Please select some property features.). I see you've commented out the Required attribute for PropertyPhoto but you might be doing custom validation with ValidatePhoto (error message: Please upload the image.) attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert)

Comment: If you use **Entity Framework** you can have a look at my answer on [Solution for “Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486072/solution-for-validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidatione/29031857#29031857). Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to track the error:

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
{
    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    throw;
}
```