# SaveChanges in Entity Framework causes error Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have added the patient and visit tables in `reg_visit` table in Entity Framework 6.1 code-first
but when run the below code, I get this error:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Code:

```
Models.VisitDoctotDb oVisitdb = new Models.VisitDoctotDb();
Models.RegVisit oReg_visit = new Models.RegVisit();

oReg_visit.Patient = oPatient;
oReg_visit.Visit = oVisit;

oVisitdb.Reg_visit.Add(Reg_visit); ===> error
oVisitdb.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Show EntityValidationErrors...

Comment: add the try catch in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7798264/1498624) to your code, go from there and if you can't solve it add the output to the question so we could help you better

Answer (score 0):

if (oPatient) was already added to the database, you mustn't add oReg_visit to DB because it is already attached.

```html
Models.VisitDoctotDb oVisitdb = new Models.VisitDoctotDb();
Models.RegVisit oReg_visit = new Models.RegVisit();

oReg_visit.Patient = oPatient;
oReg_visit.Visit = oVisit;


oVisitdb.SaveChanges();
```

this code should save your object to database

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Entity Framework** you can have a look at my answer on [Solution for “Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486072/solution-for-validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidatione/29031857#29031857).